# How to show the Navigation Bar in an iOS view?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, appdelegate

I'm opening a View from the navigationController, using the NVSlideMenuController. However, I haven't been able to show a Navigation Bar (which I definitely need).

I'm not familiar with NavigationControllers and after following a few tutorials, it still isn't clear enough to me how it works.

This is in the AppDelegate application didFinishLaunching:

```
IntroViewController* introVC = [[IntroViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"IntroViewController" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *menuViewController = [[MenuViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped]; // Your menu view controller
UIViewController *contentViewController = (UIViewController*)introVC; // The initial content view controller

menuViewController.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = false;

NVSlideMenuController *slideMenuController = [[NVSlideMenuController alloc] initWithMenuViewController:menuViewController andContentViewController:contentViewController];

self.window.rootViewController = slideMenuController;
return YES;
```

I tried adding the code to put the navbarhidden to false and it doesn't seem to work. Is there something else I missed?

Any help is very appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
MyViewController *myViewController = [[MyViewController alloc] init];

UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:myViewController];

self.window.rootViewController = navigationController;
```

This will set the `UINavigationController` as your root view controller. If you MUST use `NVSlideMenuController` (which I have 0 experience with but really don't think it is necessary), then you can do the first two lines I gave you, and set the `navigationController` as the root for the `NCSlideMenuController`.
I would recommend Apple's documentation for UINavigationController, it is an extremely useful thing to know:
https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/IOS/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html